# Exception while reading cookie using Selenium 2 HTMLUnit Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to set and then read a Cookie using the Selenium Webdriver. 
Adding Cookie works fine. 
However, when I am trying to read the cookie, an exception is thrown by Selenium.

1. I am using the Java API for Selenium.
2. The test cases are run using TestNG. ver 5.12
3. Selenium webdriver-htmlunit version 0.9.7376

**Test case code**

```
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
      import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
      .
      .
      .
      WebDriver driver = ....
    // Now set the cookie. This one's valid for the entire domain

    Cookie testCookie = new Cookie.Builder("myCookie", "cookieValue").domain("localhost").path("/").build();
    //Works fine till here
    driver.manage().addCookie(testCookie);

    //breaks here
    String cookieFromBrow = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("myCookie").toString();
    System.out.println("Cookie :- [" + cookieFromBrow + "]");
```

---

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.internal.ReturnedCookie.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Date;Z)V
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitOptions.getCookies(HtmlUnitDriver.java:851)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitOptions.getCookieNamed(HtmlUnitDriver.java:812)
at com.medomain.site.test.SampleResultPageIntlITCase.initTestPage(SampleResultPageIntlITCase.java:150)
at com.medomain.site.test.SampleResultPageIntlITCase.testFindCaseForm(SampleResultPageIntlITCase.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:702)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What was your version, again? The current Selenium version is 2.22.0 and that's using HtmlUnit 2.9.

Comment: Yes we are using an older version but it supports Cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is method `getSecure()` on `org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie` which appears to be missing.

You seem to have entered the [JAR hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell) and some of your libraries / dependencies in your project conflict with each other in the `org.apache.commons.httpclient` version. The WebDriver you use wants version 3.1. Check all the dependencies on your project, find the offending library and the version of `httpclient` that really makes in into your classpath.

Try to use the newer one of the two - if that doesn't help, good luck :).

Comment: Yes this is a JAR Hell problem. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the jar versions. Thanks for the answering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution can help to you, but I'll try.

I had a similar problem... When I was using HtmlUnit Webdriver, and I want download a file, when I have to link WebDriver with CookiesStore, my app doesn't works,  and neither show error or exception...

After several searches and debugging my app, I found that HtmlUnit loads by introspection several libraries... one of them is gson  (in my case, gson-2.3.1.jar) (apparently, my project doesn't needed this library.. wrong!).
So, I put this lib in my project, and voila... All works without problem.

I hope it can helps to you